# How to fix the scale of several choropleth maps?

Tags: python, geopandas, choropleth

I am creating multiple choropleth maps for different time frames (because I want to do a gif) and wondering if there is any way to fix the scale for each map to do easy visual comparison ?

My current code is as follows

```
years = range(2000, 2020)

# Create the images for each year
images = []
for year in years:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
    agg.plot(column="nac_"+str(year), cmap='Blues', ax=ax, legend=True, legend_kwds={'label': f'Births in {year}'})
    ax.set_title(f'Number of births in {year}')
    ax.set_axis_off()
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(f'births_{year}.png', dpi=150)
    plt.close()
    images.append(imageio.imread(f'births_{year}.png'))

# Save the images as a gif
imageio.mimsave('births.gif', images, fps=4)
```

The ouput looks like this

[image: neededthis]

From looking at it, is clear that since the limits of the color scale changes, I can't really observe how districts decline in the number of births.

Comment: Try specifying the same values of x and y limits. `ax.set_xlim()` and `ax.set_ylim()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I believe those would only affect the coordinates of the map. I don't see how those commands would limit the value of the choropleth. What would limit the max and the min?

Comment: What does this `.. the scale for each map` mean? What is the problem with your current code.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm currently graphing the number of adolescent births per district in Costa Rica. So, the current code takes a color scale that goes from 0 to 400 for the year 2000. But when it graphs the year 2001, whose values goes from 0 to 380 (because the maximum number of births decreases) it uses the same color scale, but changes the limits. Thus the decrease in the number through time cannot really be appreciated.

Comment: I added a link with the output to the question so the mistake can be more clearly observed @swatchai
Thanks

Comment: Now I see. You require an unchanging `colorbar` that represents the whole range of values. Such colorbar needs `vmin`, `vmax` and `norm` to create. WIthout specifying explicit parameters for the colorbar, the plot will create it automatically, and the colorbar you get wont be the same for each data set.

Comment: See examples here https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html

Comment: If you add new correct `animated GIF` in your question, with some useful comments, I will upvote the question, and you will get 10 points. Just edit your question and add new comments + a link of the new image in it. You will need to collect more points to be able to vote, comment, add image, etc. So it worths doing what I suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo code that demonstrates the use of normalized colorbars for the thematic maps. Read comments in the code for more explanation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import colorbar, colors
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cf

X   = [9.95, 11.06, 12.18, 9.13, 8.40, 
       11.08, 11.05, 9.86, 12.50, 7.83, 
       10.93, 11.81, 10.02, 8.54, 10.29] 

Y   = [49.74, 47.43, 49.62, 47.62, 48.48, 
       47.09, 49.53, 48.56, 48.29, 48.02, 
       49.15, 48.34, 50.22, 49.53, 47.34]

# Base values of thematic data
Z   = np.array([2.33, -0.52, 0.97, 
       -0.50,  0.21, 0.40,
       -1.69, 1.37, -1.79, 
       -0.09, 0.96, 0.12, 
       -0.03,  1.36, -0.37])

# Data statistics
zmin, zmax = min(Z), max(Z)
zavg = 0.5 + (zmin+zmax)/2

# Make-up more data sets for demo purposes
Z1 = [Z, 8+Z, Z-4]
Z2 = [9*Z, zavg+4*Z, -5*Z-zavg]

# Here I get 6 data sets for 2x3 subplots
ZZ = [Z1, Z2]

# Compute values for `norm`
#  vmin: minimum of all possible values from all data sets
#  vmax: maximum of all possible values ...
vmin = min(np.array(ZZ).flat)
vmax = max(np.array(ZZ).flat)

# Finally, compute norm
mynorm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
# Choose a colormap
mycmap = "plasma"  #viridis

# visualization
numCol, numRow = 3, 2
fig,ax = plt.subplots(ncols=numCol, nrows=numRow, figsize=(13,5),
                      subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})

fig.tight_layout()

# This plots 2x3 array of maps
# Each map has the same colorbar for its thematic representation
for col in range(numCol):
    for row in range(numRow):
        ax[row,col].set_extent([7.2, 13.7, 46.8, 50.7])
        ax[row,col].add_feature(cf.BORDERS, linewidth=0.3)
        ax[row,col].set_aspect('equal')
        ax[row,col].set_title("Row/Col: "+str(row)+"|"+str(col))
        mmin, mmax = min(ZZ[row][col]), max(ZZ[row][col])
        print(f"Row:{row}, col:{col}, minVal:{mmin:.2f}, maxVal:{mmax:.2f}")
        ax[row,col].scatter(X, Y, c=ZZ[row][col], s=100,
                        cmap = mycmap,
                        norm = mynorm, 
                        edgecolors='none',
                        transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=mynorm, cmap=mycmap),
                ax=ax[row,col],
                aspect = 12,
                shrink=0.79)
```

Output array of maps:

[image: 2x3maps]

Note that each of the 6 data sets has different min/max values. Without using `normalized` colormap, the colorbars of them will be different.

The code above should give the idea for you to adapt to your use case.

Since all the colorbars are the same, in practice you only need to plot 1 of them.

Comment: Thanks! I've been able to make it work.